# loading include php inside bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal, php-include

I have html code and it is working fine, but when I use "include" file.php bootstrap nav does not work. The user menu  - dropdown-menu is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>DASHBOARD</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DASHBOARD</a>          
                <ul class="user-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> User <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked gear"><use xlink:href="#stroked-gear"></use></svg> Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php"><svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>                   
            </div>                      
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>      
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 main">           
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="home.php"><svg class="glyph stroked home"><use xlink:href="#stroked-home"></use></svg></a></li>
                <li class="active">HOME</li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.row-->  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">HOME</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.row-->          
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                        <h4>New Orders</h4>
                        <div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-blue" data-percent="92" ><span class="percent">92%</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div>  <!--/.main-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add include php file, in the "panel-body easypiechart-panel",instead of New Orders.

```
<div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
    <?php include 'status/total_status.php'?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: errors, what does it do that it shouldn't, and what does it not do that it should?

Comment: what is your output? errors?

Comment: It should present a menu with 3 line - Profile, Settings and Logout, when we click on "user". But with the include code, it doesn't open.

Comment: I copied this code - http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar - to php file. Everything worked fine. I added this row  <?php include("status/last_update.php");?>. Now, the dropdown-content don't work, but the php file, that I included, works fine. What shall I do?